# Python で単回帰分析を実施時にエラー AttributeError 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'pledict'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Pythonで回帰分析をしようと、参考にしているサイトの通り進めるとエラーが表示されます。解決法を教えてください。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
AttributeError
'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'pledict'
```

**ソースコード**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import seaborn

df = pd.read_csv("csvのパス")
time.sleep(0.5)
x = df[['x']]
y = df[['y']]
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.plot(x,model.pledict(x))<<<ここでエラー
plt.show()
```

追記
同じ分を書き直すと同じ場所で
AttributeError
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'model'と表示されました

Answer (score 1):

綴りが違います．

- 訂正前

```py
plt.plot(x,model.pledict(x))<<<ここでエラー
```

- 訂正後

```py
plt.plot(x,model.predict(x))<<<ここでエラー
```